# When I use a method as a callback, it seems to lose access to `this`. Why?

Tags: javascript, methods, callback, this

I'm using `express` in Node to create a simple web app.  The code looks like this:

```
var get_stuff = function (callback) {
    another.getter(args, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;

        data = do_stuff_to(data);

        callback(data);
    });
};

app.get('/endpoint', function (req, res) {
    get_stuff(res.send);
});
```

When I run this, though, I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined at res.send`. The express code that's breaking starts like this:

```
res.send = function (body) {
    var req = this.req;
    var head = 'HEAD' == req.method;
```

It seems to me that the way I've constructed the callbacks is losing `this` in the `send` method. But I'm not sure how to fix it. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
get_stuff(res.send.bind(res));
```

and have a look at the [MDN documentation about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to get an idea how it works. The value of `this` is determined by *how* the function is called. Calling it "normally" (what probably happens with the callback), like

```
func();
```

will set `this` to the global object. Only if a function is called as an object method (or if `this` is explicitly set with `.bind`, `.apply` or `.call` are used), `this` refers to the object:

```
obj.fun(); // `this` refers to `obj` inside the function
```

`.bind` allows you to specify the `this` value without calling the function. It simply returns a new function, similar to

```
function bind(func, this_obj) {
    return function() {
        func.apply(this_obj, arguments);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the value of `this` is [generally determined by the call site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/3840170), and unlike in Python, accessing a method via the `.` operator does not bind its left-hand side to `this` when the method is later called.

To perform the binding, you can call `.bind` like in the older answer, or you may perform the binding by hand, wrapping the method call in another callback:

```
get_stuff(function () {
    return res.send.apply(res, arguments);
});
```

As of ECMAScript 2018, it’s also possible to use fat-arrow function syntax and rest parameters to make the above much more compact:

```
get_stuff((...args) => res.send(...args));
```