# Javascript decrementing value returns NaN

Tags: javascript, loops, nan, decrement

Good day, I'm working on a small JS loop that executes an action each X second-s randomly selected in a range, here is my current script:

```
var test = {
    lastFrame: 0,
    timeBeforeSomething: 0.0,
    
    update: function() {
        let now = Date.now();
        
        if( this.lastFrame != undefined ) {
            let delta = ( now - this.lastFrame ) / 1000;
            
            if( this.timeBeforeSomething <= 0 ) {
                this.doSomething();
                
                this.timeBeforeSomething = Math.round( ( ( Math.random() * ( 1.0 - 0.5 ) ) + 0.5 ) * 1000 ) / 1000;
                console.log( 'this.timeBeforeSomething = ' + this.timeBeforeSomething );
            } else {
                this.timeBeforeSomething -= delta;
                console.log( 'this.timeBeforeSomething -= ' + delta + ' => ' + this.timeBeforeSomething );
            }
        }
        
        this.lastFrame = now;
        
        setTimeout( test.update, 0 );
    },
    
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log( 'something' );
    }
}

test.update();
```

My problem is coming from the `timeBeforeSomething` attribute, indeed this-one is set to NaN at the second loop.

But I only: assign to it float values, and decrement value, so I don't understand why.

Here is a trace of what this script does print:

```
something
this.timeBeforeSomething = 0.672
this.timeBeforeSomething -= 0.01 => NaN
this.timeBeforeSomething -= 0.004 => NaN
this.timeBeforeSomething -= 0.012 => NaN
this.timeBeforeSomething -= 0.013 => NaN
this.timeBeforeSomething -= 0.015 => NaN
```

And from there, `timeBeforeSomething` stay equal to 0.672, do you know why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I use a method as a callback, it seems to lose access to \`this\`. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176487/when-i-use-a-method-as-a-callback-it-seems-to-lose-access-to-this-why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) your call to `test.update` to the current `this` context. Otherwise it will get the function's `this` context in which `timeBeforeSomething` is undefined:

```
setTimeout(test.update.bind(this), 1000);
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
var test = {
  lastFrame: 0,
  timeBeforeSomething: 0.0,

  update: function() {
    let now = Date.now();

    if (this.lastFrame != undefined) {
      let delta = (now - this.lastFrame) / 1000;

      if (this.timeBeforeSomething <= 0) {
        this.doSomething();

        this.timeBeforeSomething = Math.round(((Math.random() * (1.0 - 0.5)) + 0.5) * 1000) / 1000;
        console.log('this.timeBeforeSomething = ' + this.timeBeforeSomething);
      } else {
        this.timeBeforeSomething -= delta;
        console.log('this.timeBeforeSomething -= ' + delta + ' => ' + this.timeBeforeSomething);
      }
    }

    this.lastFrame = now;

    setTimeout(test.update.bind(this), 1000);
  },

  doSomething: function() {
    console.log('something');
  }
}

test.update();
```